# Blend in visual studio 2012: Missing the "resources" window i used to use in blend 4

Tags: visual-studio-2012, expression-blend, blend-2012, resourcedictionary

In blend 4 i often open a resource dictionary (i.e. "Generic.xaml") by clicking the "resources" tab (next to the property tab on the right pane), navigate to a resource and click on its icon to edit it in the designer.

In blend for visual studio 2012 i can't seem to find the resources tab? How am i then able to edit resources in resource dictionaries?

Comment: Why did someone edit the title of this question?
This is not a question for Expression blend 4. This is a question about the blend design tool in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: SimonTop -- I know exactly what you are talking about. I'm a long time blend user, and now that .NET 4.5 is out, and Blend + sketch flow for VS2012 isn't supported, I'm using VS 2012. I dearly miss the Resources explorer that Blend sports.

Comment: @Spurkiss That is no longer the case with VS2012 Update 2+. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

As of **VS2012 Update 2+** we can once again create desktop WPF apps so the **Resource** tab returns.

*"In addition, Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 and later adds support for Silverlight and WPF editing, as well as SketchFlow. Developers can now leverage a consolidated tool for all the platforms as part of a fully integrated solution with Visual Studio."* (1)

---

(1) "Microsoft Expression Changes", http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/, retrieved 2013-9-20

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming this is a XAML project. Is the Window open? Main toolbar -> Window -> Resources... is that checked? If not, check that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although I do not entirely understand you?
XAML project, what exactly do you mean?
I have a lot of various project types. This particular project is a .net 4-class library for WPF.
I can open a xaml file and edit it using the blend-designer in VS 2012.
Window->Resources - I can't find this? I can however I can find VIEW -> Other windows -> Resources. Unfortunately this does not appear to be the resources tab from blend.