# Visual Studio 2012 / Blend - Animations and UI States

Tags: expression-blend, blend, blend-2012

I am seriously confused about what to edit the animation and UI State part of my WPF Frontends with. Expression Blend 4 used to be a really good product, but MS has really [lost me](http://net-fx.blogspot.de/2012/12/current-and-future-microsoft-expression.html) in their product policies...

The Blend Insider Blog [announced](http://blendinsider.com/technical/announcing-blend-sketchflow-preview-for-visual-studio-2012-2012-08-15/) Blend some time ago, and if I can trust myself to read a table, the one on this page tells me that all Blend functionality for .Net 4.5 Applications is incorporated in Visual Studio Professional.

While I can verify this partially (Editing Control Templates etc. look good at first sight), I really wonder how i can edit UI States and keyframe / timeline animations in VS 2012? [Seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874005/how-can-i-design-an-animation-with-a-wpf-project-in-visual-studio-2012) I'm not the only one who wants to know... The Blend version that comes with VS 2012 Pro is for store apps only...On the other side, there' [smoke rising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529238/blend-in-visual-studio-2012-missing-the-resources-window-i-used-to-use-in-ble) because of missing features...

Comment: While there seems to be a real lack of question marks, I think this is still an understandable issue. Stackoverflow seems to be overrun by wannabe moderators lately. Sorry, but obviously Neutrino understood the question here...Instead of improving the quality of questions to make the FAQ site more complete some of you just remove stuff that can be answered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable Expression Blend support for WPF apps in VS2012 you need Update 2 for VS2012. That is available here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38188